# How can I copy a specific line to a specific folder? - Debian/Bash/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am trying to copy a specific line which is in a file, into a specific folder name.
And this folder must have the equal name than this line.

I have 3 folders :

- /home/my_username/bin : which contains inside of it a file, which is my script file : **switch_menu**
- /home/student : which contains inside of it, my 2 students files : **Rick and Josh**
  And inside of each of both files, there are all the subjects names followed by the respectives score they received for it.
- /home/result : which contain inside of it, my 2 subjects lessons files : **MATH and HISTORY**
  And inside of each of both files, there are the students name followed by the score they received for this specific lesson subject.

---

Here are my codes for a better understanding :

```
1. My script file | Inside of /home/my_username/bin  

#! /bin/bash

title="Switch Menu"
prompt="Please pick an option :"

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt"

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
 case $REPLY in
              1) cat /home/result/MATH >>/home/student/Rick;;
              2) echo "Goodbye !"; break;;
              3) echo "The option $REPLY does not exit !";;
 esac
done
```

---

```
2. My student files | Inside of /home/student

-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 month date time Rick
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 month date time Josh
```

---

```
3. My result files | Inside of /home/result

-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 month date time MATH
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 month date time HISTORY

cat MATH | Gives me 

Rick 7
Josh 14

cat HISTORY| Gives me 

Rick 18
Josh 11
```

---

Right now, if I run my script : **switch_menu**,

And type the choice 1, it will simply copy all the content of my **MATH** file, inside my **RICK** file.

Though in my MATH file, there is also the score for **Josh**

It shouldn't be like it.

It should be this : once I click on "1", it copies the score for each of my respectives students.

**So that for this example, it should copy** :

- **Rick 7**, inside of the Rick file.
- **Josh 14**, inside of the Josh file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to add the grades from a result file (e.g. math.txt) to the corresponding students file (e.g. rick.txt, josh.txt).

The way, that you are doing it right now
`cat /home/result/MATH >>/home/student/Rick;;`
is incomplete. You need to find a way to filter and process the information in the lines read from the math file.
I don't want to give you a complete solution, because it sounds like homework to me. But I will give you an examples:

`sh$ cat math.txt
  Mike 12
  Romeo 8
  Peter 13`

Following command

`sh$ grep "Mike" math.txt
  Mike 12`

would only return the one line.

Further you can split the lines into single columns.

`sh$ grep "Mike" math.txt | cut -d' ' -f2
 12`

would only return the 2nd column with the grade.